# callback functions in javascript event for dynamically created input

Tags: javascript

Have I made some sort of fundamental error with this approach? When the input box is actually changed, `getAdditionalFilterCallback` is always "undefined" ... it IS set to a function when someFunction is called...

SIMPLIFIED EXAMPLE:

```
function someFunction (options, selector, getAdditionalFilterCallback) {

        $(html)
          .appendTo($(selector))
          .find("input")
          .keyup(function () {
            var additionalFilter = getAdditionalFilterCallback();              
            var filters = getFilters(options, additionalFilter)
          }
    }
```

Comment: pass the input as argument to callback

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at there ... on keyup, I want to call getAdditionalFilterCallback (which takes no parameters) to get a value, then use that value in the call to getFilters.

Comment: If the problem is that the return value of `getAdditionalFilterCallback()` is undefined then we need to see that function.

Comment: no, it is that the function parameter itself is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
function someFunction (options, selector, getAdditionalFilterCallback)
{
  $(html)
    .appendTo($(selector))
    .find("input")
    .keyup(function ()
    {
      getAdditionalFilterCallback($(this));
      var filters = getFilters(options, additionalFilter)
    }
}

someFunction (options, selector, function(input)
{
  // input is the $(this) element from -> getAdditionalFilterCallback($(this));
});
```

the **getAdditionalFilterCallback** is the anonymous function you call it from the **someFunction** you exec it when **keyup** is fired

Comment: sorry, I still do not see what you are driving at. The code in getAdditionalFilterCallback is not dependent on input.

Comment: ```someFunction``` is in an external js file that may be used from many pages. ```getAdditionalFilterCallback``` should return a filter object that depends upon the particular values on the calling page at the time the keyup happens. But it does not depend on the input value itself.

Comment: maybe the getAdditionalFilterCallback is not a public function

Answer (score 0):

Much embarassment here - the actual function call is more complex, and it turns out that I had passed the function to the wrong parameter!

Thanks for everybody who tried to help!